# Wide and Narrow transformations in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a question : Wide and Narrow transformations python Spark, are found both in RDDs and Structured APIs, right ?

I mean, I guess I got the difference between wide and narrow transformations. My point is, are they exclusive for one or the other python Spark API (whether it's RDD or not)?

Wide Transformations:

- These are the operations that require shuffling data across partitions.
- This means that the data needs to be moved between executor or worker nodes.
- Some examples of wide transformations in Spark include :

  - groupBy
  - groupByKey()
  - reduceByKey()
  - aggregate()
  - aggregateByKey()
  - distinct()
  - join()
  - repartition()

Narrow transformations :

- compute data that live on a single partition meaning there will not be any data movement between partitions to execute narrow transformations
- map()
- filter()

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Dataframes are a higher abstraction of RDDs.

The wide and narrow transformations apply to both dataframe and RDD.

E.g. grouping by will cause shuffle with both, wide transformation.

Narrow transformations e.g. filter likewise apply in the same way to both and there will be no shuffling. Hence the term narrow.